# What does 0 mean in getSharedPreferences()

Tags: android

What does it mean to call `getSharedPreferences(.., 0)`? The sources doc mentions it without explanation:

```
mode    int: Operating mode.
Value is either 0 or combination of MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE,
MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE or MODE_MULTI_PROCESS.
```

See [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Answer (score 2):

according to the developer.android.com , 0 or MODE_PRIVATE is the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).

Answer (score 1):

It is the default value: MODE_PRIVATE